# Lambda calculus beta reduction specific steps and why

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

From a book I'm recently reading:

First:

`.(..)()((.))`
The outermost lambda binding  is, at this point, irreducible because it has no argument to apply to. What remains is to go inside the terms one layer at a time until we find something reducible.

Next:

`.(.)((.))`
We can apply the lambda binding  to the argument . We keep searching for terms we can apply. The next thing we can apply is the lambda binding  to the lambda term `((.))`.

I don't get it. In the first section, it says  has no argument to apply to, that I can probably understand, but then at the Next section I think the `z` can be bound to `((.))` because as you can see, `.(.)`, the body of  clearly has a `z` argument which can be bound. But the book just ignored the head  and directly bound `n` to `((.))`. I mean `.` doesn't have an `n` argument, why does it get to be bound?

Can somebody explain to me about this?

Comment: Great. I was perfectly happy not knowing about Unicode Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols; now I'm going to feel compelled to use them.

Comment: @chepner oh my is it that you can't see those symbols? I didn't realize that until I checked this question on my phone just now.

Comment: No, it's that I *can* seem them, and I was so amazed to see italicized text in a code block that I had to them up. They're a pain to type, but they look *so* right. :)

Comment: I think what you're hitting upon is the difference between a strictly-evaluated lambda calculus (your reduction steps) and a lazily-evaluated lambda calculus (the book's reduction steps).

Comment: @chepner But that Unicode is not working on my iPhone. Maybe you should not get too obsessed with it lol.

Comment: @chepner: I have these mapped to `\a` `\b` ... in my Emacs configuration. Good fun, though utterly pointless (and it's indeed still not web-safe, and _certainly_ not safe for anything where you're not sure if it even uses a proper encoding like UTF-8).

Comment: @haoformayor Hi I guess that's exactly what I'm thinking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using normal order evaluation, you can get the answer in two beta reductions

```
// beta reduction 1
λz.(λm.λn.m)(z)((λp.p)z) →β (λn.m) [m := z]
λz.(λm.λn.z)(z)((λp.p)z)

// beta reduction 2
λz.(λn.z)((λp.p)z)       →β z      [n := ((λp.p)z)]
λz.(λn.z)((λp.p)z)

// result
λz.z
```

The second reduction might seem tricky because `n` is bound to `((λp.p)z)` but the expression is just `z`, so `n` is thrown away.

---

Using applicative order evaluation, it takes one extra step

```
// beta reduction 1
λz.(λm.λn.m)(z)((λp.p)z) →β p      [p := z]
λz.(λm.λn.m)(z)((λp.z)z)

// beta reduction 2
λz.(λm.λn.m)(z)(z)       →β (λn.m) [m := z]
λz.(λm.λn.z)(z)(z)

// beta reduction 3
λz.(λn.z)(z)             →β z      [n := z]
λz.(λn.z)(z)

// result
λz.z
```

---

In this scenario, whether we use normal order evaluation or applicative order evaluation, the result is the same. Differing evaluation strategies sometimes evaluate to different results.

An important note, the reduction steps we've done above will not take place *until* `λz` is applied (depending on the implementation). In the example code you have provided, `λz` is never applied, therefore simplifying `λz`'s term is just for exercise, in this case.

All we've done is demonstrate lambda *equivalence* (under two different evaluation strategies)

```
λz.(λm.λn.m)(z)((λp.p)z) <=> λz.z
```

Comment: I get it. If I do [n := ((λp.p)z)] the answer would be λz.z

Comment: You could do `[n := anything]` and the answer would still be `z` because there is not `n` in `λn.z`'s term

Comment: At the second reduction, I thought I could do `[z := ((λp.p)z)]` and get `z` at last.

Comment: That's not how it's evaluated tho. You have an application of `(λn.z)` to `((λp.p)z)`. `(λn.z)` only binds `n`, not `z`.

Comment: I meant the `λz` in `λz.(λn.z) `

Comment: `λz` is never applied to another lambda term. At least not in the example you provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120627/discussion-between-allen-and-naomik).

Comment: I'm mildly agitated to see the statement "lambda calculus uses normal order evaluation". Various *implementations* of lambda calculus use particular evaluation strategies (and many would not reduce under a lambda at all) , but the "lambda calculus" per se does not commit to any specific strategy.

Comment: @pigworker I did mention that evaluation under `λz` wouldn't take place until it's applied. I misspoke when I said lambda calculus uses normal order evaluation. It's the only evaluation strategy I've seen in my learnings, but I suppose there's no reason other strategies couldn't be used. I will adapt my answer to avoid spreading misinformation. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 5):

Lambda notation is a bit weird to parse. IMO Haskell syntax is clearer:

```
\z -> (\m -> \n -> m) z ((\p -> p) z)
```

or, even more explicit

```
\z -> (
        (
           ( \m -> (\n -> m) )
           z
        )
        ( (\p -> p) z )
      )
```

The first reduction step is

```
\z -> (
        (
           (\n -> z)
        )
        ( (\p -> p) z )
      )
```

or

```
\z -> (
        (\n -> z)
        ( (\p -> p) z )
      )
```

then you can indeed bind `((\p -> p) z)` – not to `z` but to `n`! (Which isn't actually used at all though.)

```
\z -> (
        (z)
      )
```

or simply `\z -> z`. So, we *still* have that `z` lambda, which as the book said is irredicible. We just don't have anything else!

---

...I'm not sure if that was actually your question. If it was rather: why must we not *first* see if we can reduce `((\p -> p) z)`, then the answer is, I think, lambda calculus as such doesn't define this at all (it just defines what transformation you *can* apply, not in which order you *should* do it.<sup>Actually I'm not sure about this, correct me if I'm wrong</sup>). In a strict language like Scheme, you would indeed first reduce `((\p -> p) z)`; Haskell wouldn't do that since there's no need. Either way, it doesn't really matter, because the result is discarded anyway.

```
   ( \z -> (\n -> z) ((\p -> p) z) )
≡  ( \z -> (\n -> z) z )
≡  ( \z -> (\n -> z) foo )
≡  ( \z -> z )
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, I've used up my brain today. 2:26 Am and gotta sleep. I think I'll have to read your answer again tomorrow when my brain actually exists. lol.

Comment: Okay my way of thinking is, when I get to ( \z -> (\n -> z) ((\p -> p) z) ), can I do like: bind z to (\p -> p) z) and get (\n -> ((\p -> p) z))  and bind n to z and get ((\p -> p) z) and then (\p -> p)?

Comment: Sorry ((\p -> p) z) should be z, my bad. So it means "bind z to (\p -> p) z)" is wrong. Why?

Comment: No, you can't bind `z` to anything at all because it still comes from out of the scope. Hence my remark about the legibility of lambda syntax. `λa . b c d` is just shorthand for `λa . ((b c) d)`, i.e. the `a`-lambda is _always_ at the very outside; nothing comes after it that you could bind it to.

Comment: I personally find this a lot harder to read than the "weird" lambda notation lol. Still, nice work on a well-explained answer ＾＿＾

Comment: @leftaroundabout By scope you mean the parenthesis above right? I think I'm getting it.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that *n* is never used in the abstraction. `n` is still bound to `((λp.p)z)`, but it is immediately discarded.

```
λz.(λm.λn.m)(z)((λp.p)z) = λz.(λn.z)((λp.p)z)  Replacing m with z
                         = λz.z                Replacing n with ((λp.p)z)
```